# Are the rules of SO tagging syntax written up somewhere?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-faq

Just wondering, and can't find it via a search: is there a thread or FAQ or such on the site explaining the (obviously, very few) rules to how tagging structure works? We want to implement a tagging system, and are looking for examples of good reasoning

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does stackoverflow implement their tags functionality on their database?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40815/how-does-stackoverflow-implement-their-tags-functionality-on-their-database)

Comment: @rene No, though that's a useful link. I'm talking more about rules like lowercase, dash-separated, description writing, synonyms, etc.

Comment: This gets you in a direction http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions

Comment: @rene Yes that's a start. I'm looking for the complete, "official" (or, at least, debated in-thread) list of rules along the lines of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88003/188059)